# Onload click on picture with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, js-fancyproductdesigner

I have a website where I'm trying to auto click on picture using jQuery when site is loaded. I'm using wordpress and the code is implemented in footer. The site is https://mobimania.si/trgovina/ovitek-print-gold-mandala-copy/ and the actual picture is in "IZBERI MOTIV" section.

I have code but for some reason it doesn't work

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function($) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#mCSB_4.fpd-grid.fpd-item>picture").trigger('click');
  }, 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mCSB_4" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light mCSB_vertical mCSB_outside" style="max-height: none;" tabindex="0">
  <div id="mCSB_4_container" class="mCSB_container mCS_y_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_y" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="ltr">
    <div class="fpd-grid fpd-grid-contain fpd-padding">
      <div class="fpd-item fpd-hidden" data-title="252105" data-source="/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/252105-e1551204819312.jpg" data-search="252105">
        <picture data-img="/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/252105-e1551204819312-188x300.jpg"></picture>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<script>jQuery function() {` is invalid syntax

Comment: $("#mCSB_4.fpd-grid.fpd-item>picture")
1.what is picture, is it a class or id
2.format the element selector for better understanding

Comment: `$(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#mCSB_4.fpd-grid.fpd-item>picture").trigger('click');
      },10);
    });` assuming the image is there

Comment: need associated HTML code top, to understand what this "picture" is and also provide the code showing binding of a click event on the picture

Comment: I made you a snippet in an attempt to provide a [mcve]

Comment: mplungjan thankyou, I was just writing the snippet by my self :)

Comment: @MiranUrbas thanks for adding the snippet but it seems that you are triggering the click correctly but there is no code to handle the click event. What you want to happen on click of "picture"?

Comment: @Ronit Mukherjee on picture click the picture should appear as background to another element. Its like choosing th design

Comment: @MiranUrbas where is your code in the snippet for your expectaion?

Comment: @RonitMukherjee The image is in the other tab of the selection panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to fix

`<script>jQuery function() {`

I suggest

```
$(function() { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#mCSB_4").find("picture").trigger('click'); 
  },10); 
});
```

Your selector is wrong. You are trying to click a direct child of something that has id=mCSB_4 and both `.fpd-grid.fpd-item` classes

These will all work:

- `$("#mCSB_4").find("picture").trigger('click');`
- `$("#mCSB_4 > .mCSB_container > .fpd-grid>.fpd-item > picture").trigger('click');`
  direct descendants and
- `$("#mCSB_4 .mCSB_container .fpd-grid .fpd-item > picture").trigger('click');`
  using just the classes with spaces

**NOTE** This is assuming there is a click handler on that picture.

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function($) {
  $("picture").on("click",function() {
    console.log("clicked")
  })
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("trying to click")
    $("#mCSB_4").find("picture").trigger('click');
  }, 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mCSB_4" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light mCSB_vertical mCSB_outside" style="max-height: none;" tabindex="0">
  <div id="mCSB_4_container" class="mCSB_container mCS_y_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_y" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="ltr">
    <div class="fpd-grid fpd-grid-contain fpd-padding">
      <div class="fpd-item fpd-hidden" data-title="252105" data-source="/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/252105-e1551204819312.jpg" data-search="252105">
        <picture data-img="/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/252105-e1551204819312-188x300.jpg"></picture>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have some JavaScript errors on your page, please fix them.

About your problem: your code does not work because you are using the wrong selector, this one should work:

```
$("#mCSB_4 .fpd-grid .fpd-item > picture").trigger('click');
```

Please note the spaces, you have an element with id="mCSB_4" that contains an element with class "fpd-grid" that contains and element with class "fpd-item" which have a "picture child".

Without spaces you are searching for an element with id="mCSB_4" and those classes.